# Enabling/reading PMU from userspace

Tags: linux, arm

I would like to access the PMU from userspace, but on one of my systems, `PMUSERENR` is set to 0, which makes the rest of the PMU inaccessible.   This register is RO at EL0, so if I try to set it, I get an Illegal instruction.  Is there any way to force this on from userspace?  (any sort of standard system call etc?   I'm on a linux 4.1 system)

If not, is there any good way to get the number of clock cycles per millisecond in userspace?

Answer (score 2):

You can set up hardware performance counters from user-space using [`perf_event_open`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/perf_event_open.2.html) and read them using `read` syscall.